# Typescript and Leaflet - map zooms outside bounds

Tags: typescript, leaflet

Trying to use Leaflet from an Angular 5 application.

The map displays properly and can be panned. But I can zoom the map so that the image goes outside the boundary of the map element.

I have:

```
<div id="image-map"></div>
```

There is an import for the map:

```
import {control, MapOptions, LatLng, layerGroup, LayerGroup, Map, LatLngBounds, ImageOverlay} from 'leaflet';
```

and then in ngOnInit:

```
const w = 3376;
const h = 1768;

const themap = new Map('image-map', { minZoom: 0.2, maxZoom: 4,
  center: [0, 0], zoom: 1, attributionControl : false, 
  inertia : false, 
  zoomControl : true
   } );
const southWest = themap.unproject([0, h ], themap.getMaxZoom() - 1 );
const northEast = themap.unproject([w, 0], themap.getMaxZoom() - 1 );
const bounds = new LatLngBounds( southWest, northEast );

const overlayMap = new ImageOverlay( '/assets/images/theImage.jpg', bounds );

overlayMap.addTo( themap );

themap.setMaxBounds( bounds );
themap.fitBounds( bounds );
```

and this for the css:

```
#image-map {
width : 900px;
height : 400px;
margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
border: 1px solid #ccc; 
background: #252A2E
```

}

Presumably I'm missing an option for the map or the Overlay but I can't work out which one.

Answer (score 0):

What was missing was the style sheet for Leaflet for anyone who hits similar problems.

D'oh.